# How to jump to anchor in angular's partial view?

Tags: angularjs

I have many items in a long listview. How can my users jump to (i.e. bookmark) to a specific item by visiting mypage.html#the_item_id ?

Actually, it can when I use inline view [Sample 1], but not when I use partial view [Sample 2]. Is there a bug in the latter case, or must I use any workaround?

Thanks in advance!

Sample 1: You can visit page.html#a100 to see item 100 ::

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function MainCtrl($scope){
            $scope.items = [];
            for(var i=0; i<200; i++){$scope.items.push({id: i})}
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller='MainCtrl'>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="i in items"><a id='a{{i.id}}'>{{i.id}}</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Sample 2: Can NOT visit page2.html#a100 to see item 100, WHY? ::

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function MainCtrl($scope){
            $scope.items = [];
            for(var i=0; i<200; i++){$scope.items.push({id: i})}
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller='MainCtrl'>
    <div ng-include="'scroll_view.html'"><!-- MUST use "'...'" notation here --></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is the scroll_view.html needed by sample 2::

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="i in items"><a id='a{{i.id}}'>{{i.id}}</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Have you found a solution yet? From what I have discovered, the problem is that jqlite `element.getElementById` is returning null inside the `scroll` function. Maybe because the content does not exist in the DOM yet?

Answer (score 5):

You have to use **autoscroll** attribute on ng-include.

Check the docs here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInclude

> autoscroll(optional) – {string=} – Whether ngInclude should call $anchorScroll to scroll the viewport after the content is loaded. 
>   If the attribute is not set, disable scrolling.
>   If the attribute is set without value, enable scrolling.
>   Otherwise enable scrolling only if the expression evaluates to truthy value.

So in your case:

```
<div ng-include="'scroll_view.html'" autoscroll></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the trick! I should really go through all the doc.

Comment: So it was supposed to solve the problem, in theory. Turns out the problem is more complicated than we thought.

When I tested on Chrome 23, only the inline-implementation (sample1) works as expected. When using partial view, with or without the autoscroll setting, the page.html#anchor notation can not bring us to the destination. Situation is even worse in Firefox 17, non of above combination works. I am testing with AngularJS 1.0.3, on Windows platform.

Don't know it is just me or not. So just keep this question open to see how others might feedback. Thank you @matys84pl anyway.

Comment: This doesn't work for me either. The problem is that `element.getElementById` inside the `scroll` function returns null, so it can't find the element to scroll to. Probably async/DOM insertion related.

Answer (score 1):

I think html5Mode needs to be set to true, but I'm not certain.  See if this works for you (it did for me, but I only tested on Chrome 23 loading the page using file:///...):

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="scroll_view.html">
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="i in items"><a id='a{{i.id}}'>{{i.id}}</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </script>
    <script>
        function MainCtrl($scope){
            $scope.items = [];
            for(var i=0; i<200; i++){$scope.items.push({id: i})}
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller='MainCtrl'>
    <div ng-include="'scroll_view.html'"><!-- MUST use "'...'" notation here --></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []).
  config(function($locationProvider) {
     $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  })
```